# Is there any other way I can sort through my pokedex?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, pokeapi

This is my very first project with javascript and I am having trouble with sorting through my data. The goal is to have have the cards display in alphabetical order/reverse order and the same with displaying the id number from 1 to 151 or from 151 to 1.

here is the code

```js
const pokeContainer = document.getElementById('poke_Container')
const poke_Num = 150//This is the number of pokemon we want to display
const sortInput = document.getElementById("filter-Buttons")

//function that will fetch the object data we need
const cardDetails = async () => {
    //loop that will fetch all the pokemon details
    for (let i = 1; i <= poke_Num; i++) {
        await getPokemon(i)
    }
}

//fetches the data thats needed from the pokeapi
const getPokemon = async (id) => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`;
    //fetch responds to the promises and fetches the url
    const thepokemon = await fetch(url);
    //this returns a promise that will parse the data as text json
    const data = await thepokemon.json();
    createPokemonCard(data)
}

cardDetails();

function createPokemonCard(data) {
    const pokemon = document.createElement('div')
    pokemon.classList.add('pokemon')//actual pokemon card

    const name = data.name[0].toUpperCase() + data.name.slice(1);//capitilises the first letter/char of the name 
    const poketure = data.sprites["front_default"];
    const poketype = data.types.map((type) => type.type.name).join(" ")

    const pokemonInnerHTML = `
        <div class='image-Container'>
            <img
            src="${poketure}"
            >
        </div>

        <div class='info'>
            <h3 class=poke-Name>${name}</h3>         
            <span class="poke-id">#${data.id
                .toString()//converts the number to string so that the padstring parameter 
                /*note padstart essentially takes in a  target length and the padString and it will add whatever
                string you want to the length that you set until it is that exact length*/
                .padStart(3, "0")}</span>
            <br>
            <div class="poke-type">Type: ${poketype}</div>
        </div>
    `
    pokemon.innerHTML = pokemonInnerHTML;//javascript colleted data is now going to be displayed in html

    pokeContainer.appendChild(pokemon);//without this the pokemon cards wont be displayed within the main div
}

// const sortInput = document.getElementById("filter-Buttons")

sortInput.addEventListener('change', (event) =>{
    const sortBy = event.target.value

    switch (sortBy) {
        case 'id-asc':
            pokemon.sort((pokeA, pokeB) => pokeA.id - pokeB.id)
            break
        case 'id-desc':
        pokemon.sort((pokeA, pokeB) => pokeB.id - pokeA.id)
        break
        case 'name-asc':
        pokemon.sort((pokeA, pokeB) => {
            if (pokeA.name < pokeB.name) return -1
            if (pokeA.name > pokeB.name) return 1
            return 0
        })
        break
        case 'name-desc':
        pokemon.sort((pokeA, pokeB) => {
            if (pokeA.name > pokeB.name) return -1
            if (pokeA.name < pokeB.name) return 1
            return 0
        })
        break        
    }

    createPokemonCard(data)
})
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="/javascript/pokemon1/src/pokedex.png " alt="team-rocket png">
        <audio controls>
        <source src="/javascript/pokemon1/src/pokemon.japanese.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>   
    </header>

    <nav class="search-Box">  
        <a href="search.html"><button class="enter-Search">Click here to search pokemon</button></a>
        <span>
            <select name="sort" id="filter-Buttons">
            <option value="id-asc">ID Ascending</option>
            <option value="id-desc">ID Descending</option>
            <option value="name-asc">Name Ascending (A-Z)</option>
            <option value="name-desc">Name Descending (Z-A)</option>
            </select>
        </span>           
    </nav>



<div id="poke_Container"></div>

 <script src="pokee.js"></script> 
</body>
```

i have styled it, just didnt include the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you store your pokemon's data array in the global scope as soon as you receive the response from the API, so you can access it easily from functions.

A few notes for you:

- Remember that a variable declared inside a function can be accessed only inside that function and its inner functions unless you use var to define the variable, I recommend that you do more research about the difference between let const and var, so the pokemon variable will be undefined inside the event listener.
- In the event listener, you should then sort the pokemon data array that you stored in the global scope, and call createPokemonCard(pokemonDataArray) with the sorted array to update the html.